# lindblad_dissipator function appears to use unconventional convention

Tags: qutip

In the QUTIP documentation for the `lindblad_dissipator(a,b)` function we see that some of the $a$'s have daggers and others do not (link to documentation https://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/functions.html#qutip.superoperator.lindblad_dissipator).

The version of this equation I see in papers and wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindbladian), is instead structured so that every $b$ has a dagger, and every $a$ does not.

A consequence of QuTiPs approach is that `lindblad_dissipator(coef_a*a,coef_b*b)` is not equal to  `coef_a * np.conj(coef_b) * lindblad_dissipator(a,b)` (for complex coefficients on the operators).

Is this a different but equally acceptable convention? A minor error in QUTIP? Or am I missing something? (If it's an error it's unlikely to effect things in most cases where there will typically be another disipator with a and b swapping places)